# A character who teaches how to build wealth

Tags: characters, naming

I am looking for a character name to design a personality of a guy who teaches how to build wealth. In the real world, they are financial advisors.

Comment: Mr. Make-it? Perhaps Mr. Monet?

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against giving your character a name that is blatantly related to his character, unless you are writing a comedy. Calling the rich man "Rich Dollarman" and the policeman "Jack Law" and so forth quickly sounds very lame. Just call him "Fred Miller" or "Bob Dalton" or some such ordinary sounding name.

Comment: Thanks Jay Its for the internet based game, so i thought direct name would be better, but i agree direct interpretations are lame. "bob" sounds interesting.

Comment: To make it more interesting I think you should name the character such that it is completely perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

When you're naming characters, one of the important things you'll need to remember is keeping the names consistent within your world.  If all of your characters are from India, then having someone named Bob will be kind of strange unless he's spent a lot of time outside of India.  Venkata or something similar might work better in that case.

Also, just because a character's parents may have given them one name, doesn't mean that they actually go by that name.  Just like in real life, you can have a character go by a nickname. Venkata might go by Vinnie when he's around friends.

And one more thing - don't make two character names too similar or you'll have people confusing them.  If you have a Bob and a Rob, people will have a hard time remembering which is which.

Other than that, like Jay says in his answer, just pick something normal.

Answer (score 0):

Some names that came to mind:

- Paige ("Pay")
- Money (as a last name - Michelle Money is a real person so it's not
  an unrealistic surname)
- Rick (his nickname could be "Rich")
- Dollarman (as a last name - one of the other answers had this)

Possible combos: Rick ("Rich") Money, Paige Money, Rick ("Rich") Dollarman, Michael Johnson (completely random but you could give him a money-related nickname).

Some people said not to name your characters directly but what if your character's name is the reason why they decided to get into 'wealth building' in the first place?  **If a guy had the last name 'Money' it could motivate him to choose a career in a field related to finance.**

Or, just have their nickname be something related to money.  If your character is a financial advisor, have someone give him a **nickname related to his career**.  You can call him "Wealth" or "Dollarman" or "Mr. Money" without it being his actual name.